# Why is the state not updated when I call the setState method before the onInput does it

Tags: reactjs

I try to default a date in a date input. Here is the code

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

const DateInput = ({ handleDateInput }) => {
  const curr = new Date();
  const date = curr.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
  useEffect(() => {
    handleDateInput(date);
  });
  return (
    <>
      <label htmlFor="inputDate" className="form-label">
        Date measured
      </label>
      <div className="input-group">
        <input
          id="inputDate"
          type="date"
          className="form-control"
          onInput={(e) => handleDateInput(e.target.value)}
          defaultValue={date}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default DateInput;
```

The handleDateInput is a `useState()` `setState` from its parent. I do it like that `<DateInput handleDateInput={setDate} />`

For some reason the handleDateInput seems not be triggered when I call `handleDateInput()` anywhere before, either in the declaration or in the `useEffect()`.

Can someone explain why this could be the case and how can I fix that?
My goal is to set a default state once the component is rendered. I know that I could set the default state in the `useState` but I want the `DateInput` component to take care of what is the default.

Comment: One issue here is that your effect fires on every single render of `DateInput`, because you don't have a dependency array. This could cause an infinite render loop.

Comment: Okay, I will check on that, but even if I just move the function call out of the use `useEffect` before the render method, still the same happens.

Comment: The "react way" of doing this would be to put the state in parent, effects should be avoided when possible as they cause an extra render and increase significantly the complexity of your code

Comment: I have the feeling setting a default date in the parent violates the responsibility, do you have a suggestion how the "react way" would look, that the component sets the default itself without using `useEffect`?

Comment: It's ok for the child to call a callback that sets parent state on mount, if the child should have responsibility of knowing the default value. Also, are you looking in your console for errors? Get in the habit of reading errors, don't ignore them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useEffect without dependency array is run after each render, what happens here is that you call setState in child, parent re-render, child call setState again...causing an infinite loop.
You can solve this by adding an empty dependency array

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const curr = new Date();
    const date = curr.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
    handleDateInput(date);
  }, []);
```

Comment: That actually works, when I enter a empty dependency array a get a warning saying date and handleDateInput should be in there. Why would I not add this to the array?

Comment: A `useEffect` will be triggered any time one of the values in the dependency array changes, likely causing a rerender. In this case, you want `date` to be inside the `useEffect` body, and the `handleDateInput` to be in the dependencies array to satisfy that warning. (`handleDateInput` should be stable, since it is the setter from a `useState`)